# How to prove the absolute value of this Fourier coefficient is bounded?

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

The question is:

Let $f:[0,1)\to C $ be a step function. Prove that there exists a constant C such that for all integers $k\neq 0$, $$ \mid \,\hat{f}(k)\mid\le C\,\big/\mid k \,\mid.$$( $\hat{f}(k)$ is the Fourier coefficient of function f.)

What I have got is:

$\mid \,\hat{f}(k)\mid=\mid\int_{0}^{1}f(x)e^{-2\pi ikx}dx\mid\le\int_{0}^{1}\mid f(x)\mid\mid e^{-2\pi ikx}\mid dx=\int_{0}^{1}\mid f(x) \mid dx$

and then I don't know how to prove the rest...

Comment: Integrate and then take the absolute value of the result instead.

Comment: How to do that?

Comment: $\left|\int_{0}^{1}f(x)e^{-2\pi ikx}dx\right|=\left|\left.\frac{e^{-2\pi i k x}}{-2\pi i k}\right|_{0}^{1}\right| \le \frac{2}{2\pi |k|}$.